# Symmetrizability of generalised Cartan matrix

Tags: lie-algebras

How to prove that a generalized Cartan matrix whose diagram contains no cycles is symmetrizable?

Any hint would be sufficient.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is a generalized Cartan matrix?  What is its diagram?  What is a cycle in such diagram?  Happy New Year!

Comment: @RobertLewis Should I include all the definitions in my post?

Comment: Well, it would certainly help *me*! ;)  You might, since this seems to me to be a somewhat specialized area.  Or maybe give a link to a web-based reference.  Best of luck with it!

Comment: @RobertLewis Sorry, I cant find any referenec. I am reading Kac's book on infinite dimensional lie algebras. This is the best possible reference I manage to get http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_matrix. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Well, that's a good start.  I know it's a lot of work to pull all this stuff together . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

A size $n$ generalized Cartan Matrix $A = (A_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ is symmetrizable precisely if for all sequences $i_1,i_2,...,i_k$ of indices in $\{1,2,...,n\}$ you have $A_{i_1 i_2} A_{i_2 i_3} ... A_{i_k i_1} = A_{i_2 i_1} A_{i_3 i_2} ... A_{i_1 i_k}$.

Since $A_{ij}=0$ if there is no edge between $i$ and $j$ in the Dynkin diagram $\Gamma$ of $A$, we may assume that $i_1\to i_2\to ...\to i_k\to i_1$ constitutes a path in $\Gamma$. Then, since $\Gamma$ has no cycles by definition, any edge must be traversed in one direction precisely as often as it is traversed in the other direction.

Comment: @GA316: Is everything clear by now?

Comment: ya. thanks. sorry fro the slight delay to respond ;)